# Table id and thead not working in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

So I have this code for a table in wordpress.

```
<table id="intCall" class="tablepress">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">COUNTRY</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">CODE/PREFIX</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">RATES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="row-hover">
        <tr class="row-1 odd">
            <td class="column-1">Afghanistan</td>
            <td class="column-2">93</td>
            <td class="column-3">$0.4730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2 even">
            <td class="column-1">Afghanistan (Mobile A) Roshan</td>
            <td class="column-2">9372, 9379</td>
            <td class="column-3">$1.0110</td>
        </tr>
        .......
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2 things are not showing up. The ID, and the thead, however the tr within the thead is showing up within tbody. Not sure whats going on.

Here is a screenshot of the DOM in developer tools.
https://gyazo.com/60bfb1616773de645ff99a53e142b9a7

Here is the site
http://t4.rd-client.com/magicjack/information/international-calling-rates/

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. Are you sure you're editing the code in the right place? Also, you may want to share some more details like the browser,  WordPress version etc.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry about that, I am using Google Chrome and Wordpress Version 4.3.1

Comment: The code that you've shared here works fine for me, in the same configuration. `<thead>` and the `id` are both displayed. Perhaps its the extra dots? Try removing them and check.

Comment: <table class="tablepress">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">COUNTRY</th>
     <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">CODE/PREFIX</th>
     <th style="border: 1px solid;background-color: red;border-color: black;color: white">RATES</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="row-1 odd">
     <td class="column-1">Afghanistan</td>
     <td class="column-2">93</td>
     <td class="column-3">$0.4730</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table> your table should be like this.

Comment: The extra dots within the table are not in the original code. There are like 1k tr's in the tables so I didnt want to put them in the question. but yeah, Im curious why its showing correctly for @HareeshSivasubramanian

Answer (score 0):

I found what it was. There was a theme setting to not allow certain tags. Not sure why that exists, but it was there :D